# Kubuntu 20.04 Crackling audio when changing youtube volume

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm having this issue where the audio is crackling when changing the volume of youtube videos. I'm using USB headphones

I found many similar issues already asked online but they were either unanswered or the proposed fixes didn't help me.

As suggested in Arch wiki page for PulseAudio troubleshooting I added "load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0" to /etc/pulseaudio/default.pa and restarted pulse, but that didn't fix my issue.

Can anyone please help ?

I also tried multiple other tweaks in order to improve the audio quality, so the content of my /etc/pulse/daemon.conf looks like this:

```
daemonize = no
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 9
resample-method = speex-float-10
avoid-resampling = false
enable-lfe-remixing = no
flat-volumes = no
rlimit-rtprio = 9
default-sample-format = float32le
default-sample-rate = 19200
alternate-sample-rate = 96000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 2
default-fragment-size-msec = 125
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
```

Comment: Is it across all browsers? For me it's Chrome-specific and I am experiencing it on both Mac and Windows. There is an open issue on the Chromium bug tracker here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1166343

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the answer to my problem. It seem like this crackling noise when changing volume happens when the audio is resampled. So, in order to find out what is the default sample rate of my sound card:

```
pactl list short sinks
```

Since it indicates that my USB sound card is 44100 I changed these values to /etc/pulseaudio/daemon.conf

```
default-sample-rate = 44100
avoid-resampling = true
```

Afterwards restart pulseaudio

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

For me this completely eliminated the annoying crackling sound when changing the volume

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04.1, my sound was constantly crackling when listening to music on Youtube using Firefox (note that the sound was fine in Rhythmbox). Preventing PulseAudio from resampling fixed the issue, but the file to edit was in a slightly different location in my case:
`/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

Comment: PS/ But opening Ubuntu Settings > Sound corrupts the sound again. Issuing `pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start` restores the situation.

Comment: oh my god you're a legend. i get another kind of audio crackling issue as well where my sound will just tank and start permanently crackling while using youtube music on firefox on 3 different ubuntu machines. no idea why the crackling starts but changing the volume on youtube fixes it. i was trying to find the solution for that problem but came across this for now. it made me realize I also have crackling issues when changing youtube volume as well so hopefully they're related? will see!